# Bulk PDF Encryption Using Bat - Change in Code Required

Tags: pdf, batch-file, password-protection, pdftk

I found a code which applies random passwords to PDF files and saves it in a separate directory. Can somebody help me in modifying the code as per following requirement.

Need a single password for all pdfs in a folder
Read pdf files having spaces in their filename.
Source https://gist.github.com/glallen01/3098389

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
md out
for /f %%G in ('dir /b "*.pdf"') do (
    call:_pwgen passwd
    pdftk %%G output out/%%G user_pw !passwd!
    echo '%%G', '!passwd!' >> out/passwords.csv
)

goto :EOF

:_pwgen passwd
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set _RNDLength=8
set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
set passwd=%~1
:_LenLoop
if not "%_Str:~18%"=="" set _Str=%_Str:~9%& set /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
set _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
set /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
set _count=0
set _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
set /a _count+=1
set _RND=%Random%
set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
set _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
if !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
set passwd=!_RndAlphaNum!
endlocal&set %~1=%passwd%
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: simple - 1) remove the code to generate random passwords. 2) remove the `call` that calls that code. 3) replace `!passwd!` with a password of your choice. 4) use quotes to be safe with spaces: `pdftk "%%G" output "out/%%G" user_pw MySecretWord`

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not good with editing the code.. can you help me with the amended code?

Comment: You can use `@`SomeUser to send a message to `@someuser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 

cd/d "%~dp0" & setlocal
set "_pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
set "_pwd=your password here" && 2>nul mkdir "%cd%\out\."

for %%G in (*.pdf)do (
     "%_pdftk%" "%%~G" output ".\out\%%~nxG" user_pw "%_pwd%"
     echo/'%%~G', '%%~nxG', '%_pwd%') >".\out\passwords.csv"

endlocal & timeout /t 5 | echo\is done! & goto :EOF
```

---

You need more than only remove um `call/label`

**1.** Go to your folder, if it is the same as the bat, use `cd /d "%~dp0"`, if not  `cd /d "D:\Path\To\Folder"`

**2.** If any (or all) of the pdf files have a space in the name, use `tokens^=*`

**3.** If the destination folder exists, you can still use `mkdir`, omitting error/warning if it exists. The `2>nul` is a predictive treatment of a potential error with no relevant impact.

**4.** Replace **`for /f ...(dir/...`** to normal/regular **`for ... (*.pdf)do ...`**

**5.** Why not set and use the full path to `pdftk.exe`:

```
set "_pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
```